# What is the status on this conjecture on arithmetic progressions of primes?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, conjectures, arithmetic-progression

The Green-Tao theorem states that for every $n$, there is an arithmetic sequence of length $n$ consisting of primes.

For primes, $p$, let $P(p)$ be the maximum length of an arithmetic progression of primes whose least element is $p$.

> Is it known whether $P(p)=p$ for every prime?

(This clearly generalizes the Green-Tao theorem, asserting that long progressions show up "as soon as possible."  Note that $P(p) \leq p$ by viewing the progression mod $p$.)

Comment: Interesting conjecture. I am sure it is open.

Comment: I guess, it sounds strong enough so that it would be famous if proven. Maybe some weaker results about $P(p)$ are known?

Comment: I am not aware of anything in that direction. Even $P(p)\geq 3$ sounds difficult to me.

Comment: Already $p=11$ seems pretty tough...

Comment: I may say something silly, but the reason of such an arithmetic progression must be even and coprime with p. Suppose the length of this progression is a prime q>p, then it contains 2 multiples of p, and thus can't consist only of primes.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN in fact since the sequence in the question starts at $p$ itself, its length can be $= p$ (the delta then has to be divisible by all primes $< p$).

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to point out it can't be greater.

Comment: Regarding $p=11$: the smallest sequence is $11+n\times 210\times 7315048$ for $0\le n \le 10$.

Comment: A good question.  If true, the proof would have to be very delicate (not at all like the regularity-lemma-like proofs of Green-Tao).  If false, I think a proof would be extremely strange.  Perhaps current techniques can give some lower bound on $P(p)$, but this too sounds tricky to me.  See the following (especially the last page or so) for some discussion of other related results. http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/~conlond/green-tao-expo.pdf

Comment: I am not sure about the complete history of the problem $\ P(p)=p?\ $ I know that Siemion Fajtlowicz proposed this conjecture in 1991/2 or earlier. At that time I've got an algorithm and coded a program which gave me $\ P(13)=13.\ $ Once again, I am not a specialist, I don't know the full history here. My feeling was that $\ P(17) < 17\ ($ perhaps $\ \le 15).\ $ I feel strongly that $\ P(p) < p\ $ for every prime $\ p>13;\ $ I'd even conjecture that $\ p-P(p)\rightarrow \infty\ $ for $\ p\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: The conjecture holds up to $p=19$. See sequence A088430 in the OEIS.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, this is unknown; it is even unknown (as GH from MO suspected in a comment) whether $P(p) \ge 3$ always. An equivalent statement to $P(p) \ge 3$ is that there exists an integer $x>0$ such $p+x$ and $p+2x$ are both prime. This is a twin-prime-like problem: nobody has ever proved a statement saying that two fixed linear polynomials $ax+b$ and $cx+d$ are infinitely often simultaneously prime, or even that they must generally be simultaneously prime once. (The Green-Tao theorem converts into a statement about linear polynomials $x,x+d,x+2d,...$ in two variables $x$ and $d$; when we fix $p$ here, we have only one variable.)

On the other hand, the [prime $k$-tuples conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_k-tuple) does imply that $P(p)=p$ for every prime $p$: the corresponding polynomials are $p+x,\dots,p+(p-1)x$, and these polynomials form an admissible set (their product is not identically zero modulo any prime).

Comment: It's not the $k$-tuples conjecture which you have to use here, but rather [Dickson's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickson%27s_conjecture).