# Does every prime $p$ appear in a $p$-term arithmetic progression of primes?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic-progression

This is a follow-up to an earlier [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/307973/is-there-an-11-term-arithmetic-progression-of-primes-beginning-with-11).

The answer to that question was found on this [page](https://oeis.org/A088430). The discussion on OEIS seems to suggest that, for any prime $p$, there should exist a $p$-length arithmetic progression of primes beginning with $p$.

Is this known?

Comment: I believe that is not known.

Comment: A closely related question here in MO at which you may want to take a look later on: https://mathoverflow.net/q/260783/1593

Comment: I think such a  $ p $ -term arithmetic progression should always exist. Maybe you can try to use the notion of configuration I defined in my question "About Goldbach's conjecture" to prove it. I will have 6 days off work in a row from tonight so I'll do my best to think about it seriously and give you some news.

Comment: This could be closed as a duplicate of the thread mentioned by José?

Answer (score -3):

This is only a partial answer for now.
Define the  $ k $ order configuration of an integer  $ n $ as the sequence  $ (n\mod p_{i})_{1\leq i\leq k}$. Such a sequence defines a unique residue class modulo  $ P_{k} $, with  $ P_{k} $ the  $ k $ -th primorial.

Now let's consider the primes less than  $ p $ and let $C(p) $ denote an integer such that  $ p $,  $ p+C(p) $ , ...,  $ p+(p-1)C(p) $ are all prime.
Fix  $ k $ large enough and denote with  $ C_{i}(p)=C(p)\mod p_{i} $. Necessarily  $ p_{i}<p $ implies  $ C_{i}(p)=0 $. One can take  $ C_{\pi(p)}(p)=1 $ .

Actually it suffices that none of the numbers $ C_{i}(p), 2C_{i}(p),...,(p-1)C_{i}(p) $ be equal to $p_{i}-(p\mod p_{i}) $ , which can be achieved by taking for $C_{i}(p) $ the number  $p_{i}-h_{i} $ with  $ h_{i} $ greater than 1, less than  $ p_{i} $ and coprime with  $2(p\mod p_{i}) $. That way you finally obtained a residue class modulo  $ P_{k} $ whose less positive representant fulfills your requirements.

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Comment: Probably because the method doesn't work (you ensure indivisibility by small primes, but the numbers could still have a large prime factor. There is no suitable choice of k.)

Comment: The sequence  $ C(p), 2C(p),\cdots \frac{p-1}{2}C(p) $ forms an arithmetic sequence of primality radii of  $ p+\frac{p-1}{2}C(p) $. This may help to bound  $ k $  in terms of  $ p $.

Comment: In other words,  $ C(p) $ is a primality radius of  $ p+C(p), p+2C(p),\cdots p+(p-2)C(p) $. Note also that the proportion of primality radii of  $ n $ is greater than  $ \frac{a}{\log^{2} n }$ for some absolute  $ a>0 $. So that if should suffice to require  $ (\frac{a}{\log^{2}(p+pC(p))})^{p-2}>\frac{1}{p+pC(p)} $.